# Preload upselling products with ajax

Tags: product, ajax, up-sells

How can I preload the Upselling products with ajax (after loading all the elements of the page).

It is also possible to use prototype for that ? If yes how to proceed to do that task ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "preload"?

Comment: By "preload" I mean that the upselling products should be loaded after loading the whole page contents...

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible with prototype.

This task is too big to answer it in details (at least for me) but if you ask me, you should do something like this:

1. Implement your own module
2. Implement your own controller for the ajax request, which creates the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` set `Mage::register('product', Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(passed productId)`, wraps it into JSON and `$this->getResponse()->setBody($json)`
3. implement a few lines of prototype which get the [json from controller via ajax](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/) and then put it via `$('id of div').insert(content)` into the page